# How can I select a DOM element, which name is changing

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-selectors

I have this DOM elelement, where the part of the name of the menu [ **v15rco8kc2** ] is changing for every call of the document. How Could I use a joker in the QuerySelector?

`document.querySelector("#menu-v15rco8kc2 > div:nth-child(1) > button > span.Typography-module__lVnit.Typography-module__Nfgvc.Button-module__Imdmt")`

Comment: @Reyno thanks, but could you help me to define the query? Do I need an attribute selector for that? And how can I formulate the syntax for the JS path in the selector. Sorry but I am novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS selectors, you cannot use a *wildcard* directly to match part of an *attribute* value.
You can use [`attribute selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_4) to match elements based on a partial *attribute* value.

**Demo:**

```html
  <style>
    /* Just for styling purposes */
    button {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #3498db;
      color: #ffffff;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>

<!-- Dynamic ID element -->
<div id="menu-v15rco8kc2">
  <div>
    <button>
      <span class="Typography-module__lVnit Typography-module__Nfgvc Button-module__Imdmt">
        Click me!
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  //get the element using the attribute selector with ^ for ID starting with "menu-"
  const dynamicElement = document.querySelector("[id^='menu-'] > div:nth-child(1) > button > span.Typography-module__lVnit.Typography-module__Nfgvc.Button-module__Imdmt");

  //add a click event listener for demonstration purposes
  dynamicElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('Element clicked!');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! This opens my eyes, I learnt much with your answer

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair, you are most welcome:)